# Google Play Games testing with a bunch of fake scores

Tags: google-play-games

I'm using the Google Play Games Leaderboards for my game and I want to generate my own presentation within the game. Is there a way I can seed a leaderboard with something like 100 fake scores so I can check the UI all works?

Comment: It will be much easier to mock up the leaderboard UI in your own class vs. trying to get 100 scores.  Basically there is no way to "seed" the leaderboard.

Comment: That is pretty much what I do for layout but it won't test stuff like finding players ranked near yourself. Still it answers my question, thank you!